# Visibility of live chat bubble

Tags: chat, customer-support, avatars

I have been asked to find out if there's any pattern when it comes to the live chat bubble display. The thing is we currently keep visible not only the Hubspot bubble, but also an extra layer with an avatar as well as this message: "Got any questions? I'm happy to help".
I was wondering if we should keep visible only the bubble as that's probably enough for the user. Any thoughts on this?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already posted an answer, but if you are able to include screenshots of your current design it might help to improve my answer or get more specific answers from other people.

Comment: Thanks @musefan Just added a screenshot of how the bubble looks like. Please note that it's placed in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it really depends on your site and how intrusive it is to the user's experience. If there is potential for it to obscure information that the user is trying to read then it's probably going to annoy your user, which is not what you want.

However, this can easily be overcome by including a simple "minimise button" so the user can choose to hide the chat bubble if they want to get it out of the way.

I would suggest you to keep your design as you want it to work but try to ensure it doesn't take up more space than it needs to. Then include a "close" button that upon clicking will minimise the elements so that the user only sees something like a little tab saying "Live Chat". This can then be tucked away in the corner of the page so it doesn't affect the users experience. That way, if they want it later they can just click that to bring the original elements back.